# how to decrease page load time with some errors 404 using apache on windows vista

Tags: php, performance, apache, http-status-code-404

When I develope page I use xampp package host site locally.
Every time I refresh page I have to wait long for elements that resolve with http status 404.
The picture shows how this looks on timeline. Please provide me with resolution to speed up
page load with missing elements.
[image: chorme developer tools with network panel on it]

Comment: Why are you getting the 404s? Are the urls giving 404s outside of your control or local resources?

Comment: I get 404s because page browser want to display images uploaded by another developing team member on his local server (we share database, but every developer has his own Apache environment). So the red ones are valid but on the other machine;

Comment: If his site relies on these images and are in the database you share and you are developing the same site why don't you have those images? Surely they are a common asset of your project? - Edit What I'm getting at is, can't he send you the pictures or if you're using something like git, commit them to the repo for you to get?

Answer (score 0):

I can not see in your screenshot what is actually happening. Is it your local web server that takes a long time to reply with 404? Or are you attempting to use non-local resources?

Edit: from your answer to another comment I assume that it's your local web server that does not find (what should be) local resources and replies with 404. => Check your server config to make sure that it does not do anything silly like rescanning ALL directories for every request.

Comment: _Is it your local web server that takes a long time to reply with 404?_ @Germann Yes, my local server takes long time to reply with 404, I use local resources. How to "Check server config to make sure that it does not do anything silly like rescanning ALL directories for every request"? I don't know what I am looking for...

Comment: Most of Apache configuration options can be overridden for each directory in .htaccess [(dot)htaccess] files. You may want to look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/sections.html and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/configuring.html. <Directory> and <Files> directives is likely to be most suitable